# Open MultiDocTemplate without open File

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have generated a Visual MFC project with a `CMultiDocTemplate`.
New and File open is already implemented. But I want now to open a database and query the data.

Under `CDocument::OnOpenDocument` I could read that it would be possible to write an application for that. But I have no idea how to open a document with an attached view without open an file.

What I need is a function `OnOpenDB(LPCTSTR tableName)` which creates the document and the view but not trying to open a file and extent the table name.

Google did not help me. I could not find any useful documentation.

@Adrian,
is there maybe another solution?
Finally I want to use more than one template for different functions.
In your solution I am missing a possibility to send the table name to the doc for doing the database query and provide the data to the view.
Can I do it in override the template class?
In your code, is dynamic_cast<CMyDoc *> ... ceating the view?

So finally I would need a public function which allows me to send a request for a new document with the table name.
Is this possible?

**Update:**
I tried to override CMultiDocTemplate::OpenDocumentFile(...), but it does not work. It seem that this function is not virtual.
Therefore I created a OpenDocumentFile(...) inside the override of the CMultiDocTemplate

```
CDocument* CStreamAuswertungMDT::OpenDocumentFile(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, BOOL bAddToMRU, BOOL bMakeVisible)
{
CDocument* pDoc = CreateNewDocument();
if (pDoc == NULL)
{
    TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "CDocTemplate::CreateNewDocument returned NULL.\n");
    AfxMessageBox(AFX_IDP_FAILED_TO_CREATE_DOC);
    return NULL;
}
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
BOOL bAutoDelete = pDoc->m_bAutoDelete;
pDoc->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;   // don't destroy if something goes wrong
CFrameWnd* pFrame = CreateNewFrame(pDoc, NULL);
pDoc->m_bAutoDelete = bAutoDelete;
if (pFrame == NULL)
{
    AfxMessageBox(AFX_IDP_FAILED_TO_CREATE_DOC);
    delete pDoc;       // explicit delete on error
    return NULL;
}
ASSERT_VALID(pFrame);

// avoid creating temporary compound file when starting up invisible
if (!bMakeVisible)
    pDoc->m_bEmbedded = TRUE;

if (!pDoc->OnNewDocument())
{
    // user has be alerted to what failed in OnNewDocument
    TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "CDocument::OnNewDocument returned FALSE.\n");
    pFrame->DestroyWindow();
    return NULL;
}

// it worked, now bump untitled count
pDoc->SetTitle(lpszPathName);
pDoc->OnDocumentEvent(CDocument::onAfterOpenDocument);
InitialUpdateFrame(pFrame, pDoc);
return pDoc;
}
```

This is now working for me!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to call `CWinApp::OnFileNew()` (this will create an untitled document and a view) and then another method that will be transferring the data from the DB and setting the title?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a bit careful but you *can* do this by creating a local (static) 'copy' of your `CMultiDocTemplate` object and then manually calling `OpenDocumentFile()` on that with a `nullptr` argument:

```cpp
static CMultiDocTemplate MY_tmplate(IDR_MYDOC, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyDoc), RUNTIME_CLASS(CMDIChild), RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView));

void OnOpenDB(LPCTSTR tableName)
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = dynamic_cast<CMyDoc *>(MY_tmplate.OpenDocumentFile(nullptr));
    //... do stuff with pDoc (using `tableName` to probe the database, maybe)
    //
}
```

You will need to be careful when initializing any required data members and any limits, *et cetera*, in the `pDoc` object and its associated view(s).

You can set the document's filename/path at any stage, using the [`SetPathName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdocument-class?view=vs-2019#setpathname) base class function; or you can just change the displayed title (that shown in the view's frame windows) with [`pDoc->SetTitle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdocument-class?view=vs-2019#settitle).

Alternatively, rather than using a local (copy) document template, you could add a member to your application class to run through its list of 'installed' templates, looking for a match to a given string identifier:

```cpp
CMultiDocTemplate *MyApp::GetDocTemplate(CString name)
{
    POSITION dtPos = GetFirstDocTemplatePosition(); CString dtName;
    while (dtPos != nullptr) {
        CMultiDocTemplate *mdTmp = dynamic_cast<CMultiDocTemplate *>(GetNextDocTemplate(dtPos));
        if ((mdTmp == nullptr) || !mdTmp->GetDocString(dtName, CDocTemplate::docName)) break;
        if (dtName == name) return mdTmp;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Then, if that function returns a non-NULL pointer, use that to call `OpenDocumentFile`. For a list of the various string components you can use to match the relevant template, see the [`CDocTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdoctemplate-class?view=vs-2019#getdocstring) documentation.

Comment: see my comment above.

Comment: @HGA I have added some more information to my answer. You can use the `tableName` parameter in the function, to do whatever you need to with your database. Also, I've added a more general way to get any one of the application's templates.

Comment: @HGA Also, calling the 'OpenDocumentFile' does (or should) create the associated view; this is what `OnFileNew` does internally, IIRC.

Comment: the `GetDocTemplate` function gives me the a pointer to an existing DocTemplate. But I still have to write my own version of the `CMultiDocTemplate`, because due to the fact that I can not use the standard `OpenDocumentFile`. This will fail, because it is only a table name and not a file path.

Comment: @HGA `OpenDocumentFile` doesn't need a filename - hence the `nullptr` argument. It will create a ***new*** empty document+view pair. You can then populate that doc from your database. Maybe you are confusing what a `CDocTemplate` represents with some kind of template document. Your problem is now unclear to me.

Comment: when I call `OpenDocumentFile` with `nullptr`I got a doc and a view, but if call `GetDocument `  I do not get any reference to my table name. Because the name is than the default one. 
How can I set the doc title to the table name, when I dont have any doc pointer on the function which calls `OpenDocFile`.
If I call this function `OpenDocFile` with a nullptr, that nothing else than a neu document. 
In this case I have to override this function, but I have not found any possibility.

Comment: Did you see that part in my answer where I mentioned `pDoc->SetTitle()`?

Comment: yes I did. The problem is, that the `OnInitUpdate` will called before `OpenDocFile` returns bach the `CDocument*`. So on `OnInitialUpdate` I have only the default name.